# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: url, mamp

I've cloned an existing Craft site into MAMP Pro, set up my database in sequel pro and am able to access the site's homepage when I go to the URL I set up in MAMPS hosts. But whenever I click on a link, or try to access /admin, I get the following

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /(page name) was not found on this server.

I'm sure it's something simple, probably something I'm missing when I set up the site locally, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going to yoursite.com/index.php/(pagename). If that works, check out this article on how to remove it: https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

Comment: Adding index.php did indeed make it go to the page. Turns out there is already a htaccess file with the contents as that doc says in there. Removing it doesn't help either...

Comment: ahhh solved it. It was me being a bit of a fool. The file was htaccess and not .htaccess, so the rewrite wasnt getting added. Thanks, that article pointed me in the write direction.